# Animation on button image when tapped

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, viewcontroller

I'm new to Swift and to stackoverflow so please comment for any improvements. I can make to my asking of questions!

I have created a `UIButton` that has an image. When tapped, the image is supposed to change to another image. Currently, once tapped, it '**flashes**' with the image it is supposed to change to and then immediately changes back to the original image.

I created an outlet:

```
@IBOutlet var buttonImage: UIButton!
```

Then I added this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Change image.

    buttonImage.setImage(UIImage(named:"image1.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonImage.setImage(UIImage(named:"image2.png"),forState:UIControlState.Highlighted)

}
```

Help is gratefully received.

EDIT - added error screenshot.[errorscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhoLV.png)

Comment: `UIControlState` is `Highlighted` when the button is being touched.

Comment: You forgot the keyword `func` before your `btnTap` method declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `viewDidLoad` code like this

```
buttonImage.setImage(UIImage(named:"image1.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
buttonImage.setImage(UIImage(named:"image2.png"),forState:UIControlState.Selected)
```

Now change you `IBAction` like this

```
@IBAction func btnTap(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi - thank you for your help. The IBAction coming up with a consecutive declarations error on btnTap

Should anything be called after IBAction?

Comment: Don't understand what you try to say. You need to bind this Action with your button. Have you done that.

Comment: Yes - I created the IBAction by ctrl dragging from the button to the view controller and it created it like this:

    @IBAction func btnTap(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.selected = !sender.selected
    }

However, when deleting 'func' it produces a consecutive declarations error

Comment: i have forgot to write `func`. Check my updated answer. Try that

Comment: I initially thought it was this and added func, but upon pressing the button in the simulator it crashes and produces a Thread 1 SIGABRT error.

It is worth noting that the button obviously is connected to another outlet and action which enables it to perform its main function - could this be an issue?

Comment: Forget that - I forgot to delete the old connection - thanks a bunch :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign two images for the button like the screenshots below. [image]

[image]

As you can see I have state config as Default and Selected.

Later on the action of button you can do

```
@IBAction btnTapAction(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.selected{
        sender.selected = false
    }
    else{
        sender.selected = true
    }    
}
```